# A non-trivial example of a Riemannian manifold with universal covering $N^2\times \Bbb R$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, covering-spaces

I looking for  an **non-trivial** example of complete Riemannian $3$-manifolds such that its universal covering 
 isometric to a Riemann product $N^2\times \Bbb R$ where $N^2$ is a complete
$2$-manifold with non-negative sectional curvature.

means of "non-trivial":  $M$ not be $N^2\times \Bbb R$.

Comment: Just checking, you want the *universal* cover to be $N\times \mathbb{R}$ (in particular, $N$ is simply connected)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are posting numerous questions and not responding to (or accepting) any of the answers we work hard to post. It would be nice if you participated once we post answers.

Comment: How about $N^2 \times S^1$? Of course even less trivial examples are possible; look up mapping tori.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Please accept my apology. I done it.

Comment: Besides the examples suggested by @QiaochuYuan, there are some compact examples which are not products $N^2 \times S^1$ nor mapping tori but which fiber in the orbifold category over the infinite dihedral orbifold $\mathbb{R}/D_\infty$. One has generic fiber $S^2$ and two singular fibers being projective planes. The other has generic fiber $T^2$ and two singular fibers being Klein bottles.